# Angular 6 ngrx store action from a feature being listened by other feature reducer

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have two features, Orders and Items. Inside the orders feature i have a component that dispatch an action.

In a nutshell it looks like this :

```
constructor(store: Store<OrdersStateContract>) {

    this.orders_subs = store.pipe(select('orders')).subscribe( (orders) => {
      this.orders = orders.orders;
    });

    this.store = store;
}

ngOnInit() : void {
    this.store.dispatch( new LoadOrders({}) );
}
```

And i realized that when i dispatch the action LoadOrders, it's being caught by the items feature reducer. Is it a common behaviour ? or there's something wrong ?

**orders.module.ts** :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
],
imports : [
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('orders', OrdersReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([OrdersEffects]),
],
providers : [
    OrderService
]
})
```

**items.module.ts** :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    /*not important*/
  ],
  imports : [
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('items', ItemsReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ItemsEffects])
  ]
})
```

**items.reducer.ts**

```
export const ItemsReducer = (state: ItemsStateContract = initialState,
                             action: ItemActions) => {


    switch (action.type) {
        case ItemActionTypes.ItemsFromOrderLoadSuccess:
            return adapter.addAll(action.payload.items, state);

        default:
            return state;

    }
};
```

**orders.reducer.ts**

```
export const OrdersReducer = (state: OrdersStateContract = initialState,
                              action: OrderActions) => {

  switch (action.type) {

    case OrderActionTypes.LoadOrders: {
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload.orders, state);
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; It's a normal behavior.

It is as simple as this :
Every dispatched action at any level can be catched by any effect and any reducer. (only the effect or reducer can decide to do something with it or ignore it)

In the effects you can use the [ofType](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/90752b5f4d89194275d40ff12bd9c5c887c58682/src/actions.ts#L17) custom rxjs operator in ngrx. (basically its a [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) by action type).

In the reducers you can check the action type and change the state for the actions you want.

Comment: But in my reducer, i explicitly said the types of actions it should receive, so, that doesn't matter ? It doesn't change anything ?

Comment: Edited the question with them.

Comment: I think that the switch case is doing its job correctly, I suggest to debug or console.log the `action.type` and `OrderActionTypes.LoadOrders` and `ItemActionTypes.ItemsFromOrderLoadSuccess` values to see if the values are what you are expecting.

Comment: both, on items reducer and order reducer logged "[Order] Load Orders" as action type.

Comment: What are the values of `OrderActionTypes.LoadOrders` and `ItemActionTypes.ItemsFromOrderLoadSuccess` ?

Comment: ItemsFromOrderLoadSuccess = '[Item] Item from order load success';
LoadOrders = '[Order] Load Orders';

Comment: You mean that whats happening is that `"[Item] Item from order load success"  ==  "[Order] Load Orders"` is evaluated to true in javascript. Its impossible, there must be something wrong somewhere, needs to debug it.

Comment: This answer is right. "i explicitly said the types of actions it should receive", this is just for type checking inside the reducer - but it gets passed every action that you dispatch.